# background color of <a href> not displaying properly inside list

Tags: html, css

I'm just trying to create a tab buttons by putting some hyper links inside list within unordered list. After then i want to change the color of tab when mouse is hovered over it. In my below code i was able to change the color to green but it's not covering the tab, instead some space exists on right and left side of link `<a>` [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
   #header ul {
        list-style: none;

        margin: 0; 
    }

        #header li {
        float: left;
        padding:10px;
        padding-left:12px;
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
        background:red;
        margin: 0;

    }

    #content {
    clear:both;
    }

    #header a {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        color:#000000;

        }

        #header a:hover {
        background:#00FF00;

    }

    #header{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    }
   #content{
   position:relative;
    top:60px;
   }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">

<h1></h1>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">This</a></li>
    <li id="selected"><a href="#">That</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Other</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>

</ul>

</div>


<div id="content">
    <p>CONTENT HERE .....</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/z5DG6/3/

Your `a` has to be a block element so that it takes full width of your `li`. Also removed padding from li and added it to a only. You can play with js fiddle.

Comment: @Sukumar Ramadugu - glad it is what you needed. Just accept the answer so future users can be sure that it is a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

Other than `float:left;padding:0;margin:0`, put all styling on the A tag, **not the LI tag**. Use `diplay:block` on the A tag to enable margin and padding.

See my tutorial: [I love lists](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/)

Answer (score 2):

Because you set a padding for `li`, the remaining red space is the space between `li` borders and the inner `a`. For you case, you can set the `hover` on `li`:

```
...

#header li:hover {
    background:#00FF00;
}
```

<s>`#header a:hover { background:#00FF00; }`</s>

Comment: Wow..i'm thinking that hover can be applied only to <a> element. Thanks for this. It solved my problem.

Comment: @Sukumar Ramadugu - :hover will work on all elements except in IE6 where it will work only on a.